# Run time initialisation of peewee database for different database backends

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I'm trying to write a module that is (somewhat) database independent. I want to define my peewee models and then connect to the database at runtime using the `init` method of the database object.

When I pass a Sqlite connection string this works as expected, e.g.

```
>>> app.db.init('sqlite://mydb.sqlite')
```

Connects to the database and everything works as expected. But when I try the same with a postgres connection string I get an error;

```
>>> app.db.init('postgresql://username:password@localhost/mydb')
...
peewee.OperationalError: FATAL:  database "postgresql://username:password@localhost/mydb" does not exist
```

I can get the `init` method to connect if I use separate parameters;

```
>>> app.db.init('mydb', username='username', password='password')
```

But this doesn't translate well between different database backends.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of getting `init` to work with connection URIs?

Comment: From further reading of the documentation it appears that the Sqlite method works because the first argument of the SqliteDatabase init is the database file name and my first example isn't using a database URI.

But the documentation, particularly here - http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#connecting-using-a-database-url and here - http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#db-url would indicate that I can use the `playhouse.db_url.connect` function to return a database connection and then pass that to `db.init`. Except that raises an error as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After some interaction with the Peewee author it would seem that the answer is to use the `Proxy` object - http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/database.html#dynamically-defining-a-database

in my models module I do;

```
database_proxy = pw.Proxy()
...
class Blah(pw.Model):
    column_one = pw.CharField()

    class Meta:
        database = database_proxy
```

Then to connect at run time I do;

```
>>> from playhouse.db_url import connect
>>> import models
>>> db = connect('postgresql://username:password@localhost/mydb')
>>> models.database_proxy.initialize(db)
```

Then I can interact with my model objects normally. This way I can switch between different database backends and just have a connection URL string in my application config to switch between them.

Answer (score 0):

I think I've worked out a way to do this. It's a bit clunky so if anyone has a better suggestion I'm all ears. I'm creating a `connect` object and then passing it's attributes to the `db.init`. Like this

```
>>> from playhouse.db_url import connect
>>> import models
>>> db = connect('postgresql://username:password@localhost/mydb')
>>> models.db.init(db.database, **db.connect_kwargs)
```

This seems to work with any valid Peewee backend.

Comment: Except it doesn't work with Sqlite. If I change the connection string in the example above to `sqlite:///Users/andy47/temp_db.sqlite` the statements all execute. As soon as I try and query any model I get an error message; `OperationalError: FATAL:  database "Users/andy47/temp_db.sqlite" does not exist`